# Why my System.out.println is not working when I add a for loop after?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have written this code:

```
public class Hej {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            char[] ch = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
            int alfa = ch.length;

            System.out.println(alfa);

            for (int i = 0; i<alfa; i++) {
                System.out.print(ch[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            for (int i = 24; i <alfa; i--){
                System.out.print(ch[i] +  " ");
            } 


    }
}
```

This is what is outputted:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v x y z 

z y x v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a
```

My `System.out.println(alfa)` is not printed. 
But when I take away the for loop from the code and just choose to print alfa, then it gets printed.  I am last minute studying for an exam and I don't get it.....

Thank you :) !

Comment: **That** is an error I can't reproduce with that code. I get a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` however...

Comment: Try replacing `for (int i = 24; i <alfa; i--){` with `for (int i = alfa-1; i >= 0; i--){`

Comment: Hey it works fine for me at https://ideone.com/cBFOJ8 except for that run time error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran your program, it printed the variable alfa. Try running it again. And for the second for loop, change it to this:

```
    for (int i = 25; i >= 0; i--){
         System.out.print(ch[i] +  " ");
    }
```

Your original loop was endless.

Comment: Thank you. So it seemes to be that if I put i = alfa (which is 26 it does not work). But i = alfa - 1 works.  Why does it not work at 26? There are 26 letters to print so why can't it start printing at 26? I

Comment: Because an array always starts at 0. Even though there are 26 elements in your array, 'a' is in ch[0] and 'b' is in ch[1]. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

those lines of code will make infint loop

```
for (int i = 24; i <alfa; i--){
            System.out.print(ch[i] +  " ");
}
```

because the condition will not braked  and i will be less than alfa for ever

You should do this

```
   for (int i = 24; i >= 0; i--){
        System.out.print(ch[i] +  " ");
   }
```

Comment: This is not what he asked

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

         //u forget to add char 'w'
         char[] ch = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v','w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
         int alfa = ch.length;

         System.out.println(alfa);

         for (int i = 0; i<alfa; i++) {
             System.out.print(ch[i] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();

         for (int i = 25; i>=0; i--){
             System.out.print(ch[i] +  " ");
         } 

 }
```

In the second loop your condition is wrong it should be i>=0.

Answer (score 0):

The loop in no way should affect whether or not alfa gets printed because your print statement comes before the loop. You do, however have an infinite loop here.

```
 for (int i = 24; i <alfa; i--){
                System.out.print(ch[i] +  " ");
            }
```

'i' will always be smaller than alfa and you're not incrementing 'i' or decrementing alfa so this will run forever.